# Reorder SQL Data (Football data)

Tags: sql

I want to reorder the data on the goals and not on the standing. My code works but My code reorders the Clubs on the standing. I know about the DESC function but when I will at that I get an error. Code below

Working:

```
select f.ClubName, u.StandID, DV/13 as Doelpunten_per_wedstrijd 
From fact f
join uitslag u
on u.StandID = f.StandID
```

Error:

```
select f.ClubName, u.StandID, DV/13 as Doelpunten_per_wedstrijd DESC
From fact f
join uitslag u
on u.StandID = f.StandID
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to put order by

```
select f.ClubName, u.StandID, DV/13 as Doelpunten_per_wedstrijd 
From fact f
join uitslag u
on u.StandID = f.StandID
order by  Doelpunten_per_wedstrijd DESC
```